# ASP.Net Development Server SVG File Serving for CSS background-image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, html, asp.net-development-serv

I'm having some trouble getting an SVG file set as a background of an element in an MVC 3 Site (Razor View Engine) and wondering if the ASP.Net Development Server (Cassini?) is properly serving the SVG file.

My SVG file is located at `/img/plus.svg` and here is it's contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 25 25" enable-background="new 0 0 25 25" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#231F20" points="25,8.621 16.38,8.621 16.38,0 8.621,0 8.621,8.621 0,8.621 0,16.379 8.621,16.379 8.621,25 
    16.38,25 16.38,16.379 25,16.379 "/>
</svg>
```

The css rule I'm using to set the background is this:

```
.plusIcon { background-image: url(@Url.Content("~/img/plus.svg")); }
```

I've also added this to my Web.Config `<system.webServer><staticContent>` section:

```
<!-- Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad -->
<remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
<remove fileExtension=".svgz"/>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="images/svg+xml" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="images/svg+xml" />
```

When I navigate to the url `/img/plus.svg` the file is downloaded properly.

Is this just a Dev Server problem, should I try in IIS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out this is just a Cassini, **ASP.Net Development Server problem**.  When uploaded to a **proper IIS Site** the SVG files are **served properly**.

Comment: Thanks for that - I just came across the exact same problem. Saved me a couple minutes googling :-)

Comment: Switching you VS project to deploy to a "Local IIS Web Server" in the configuration works for me. However, IE9 still won't display it unless you have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` in your `<head>` section.

Comment: Would also be nice to know how to fix/tweak Cassini to get it to render SVG.

Comment: This problem should be addressed by Microsoft.

Comment: @JeanJimenez - It really should. Annoying to say the least.